# Conditional query chain with join

Tags: javascript, knex.js

Trying to run the following query with `knex`:

```
builder.from(PageModel.tableName).where((builder) => {
      if (this.filters.accountId) {
        instance
          .innerJoin(
            PageAccountModel.tableName,
            `${PageModel.tableName}.id`,
            `${PageAccountModel.tableName}.pageId`,
          )
          .innerJoin(
            AccountModel.tableName,
            `${PageAccountModel.tableName}.accountId`,
            `${AccountModel.tableName}.id`,
          )
          .where(`${AccountModel.tableName}.id`, this.filters.accountId);
      }

      if (this.filters.type) {
        builder.where('type', this.filters.type);
      }
    });
```

Keep getting error:

```
error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "account"
at Connection.parseE (/home/jakov/Projects/platform/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:604:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (/home/jakov/Projects/platform/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:401:19)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/jakov/Projects/platform/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:326:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:301:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:235:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23)
```

NOTE: This is run from within an object on whose fields the filters are kept (notice `this.filters`).

EDIT: I want to grab only the `page` table.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to write your query with conditional parts you can do it like this:

```
const query = knex(PageModel.tableName);

if (this.filters.accountId) {
  query
    .innerJoin(
      PageAccountModel.tableName,
      `${PageModel.tableName}.id`,
      `${PageAccountModel.tableName}.pageId`,
    )
    .innerJoin(
      AccountModel.tableName,
      `${PageAccountModel.tableName}.accountId`,
      `${AccountModel.tableName}.id`,
    )
    .where(`${AccountModel.tableName}.id`, this.filters.accountId);
}

if (this.filters.type) {
  query.where('type', this.filters.type);
}

// check the query output by
console.log(query.toSQL().sql, query.toSQL().bindings);
```

This is possible because query builder is mutable and additive, so you can add more clauses to it also after the initialization.

I'm pretty sure that above is the code you wanted to write, but I have no idea if it will result correct results for you :)

Comment: I'm using this and seem to be having a problem. I get the desired rows from the `page` table, but the `id` column has the wrong value when I filter by `account.id`. It's actually the value of the `account.id`.

Comment: I'm aware of the identifier syntax, but I still want to get all from the `page` table without having to specify every single column in there. Also, there's no `toSql` method in the `query` object...

Comment: The method is `.toSQL()` not `.toSql()`. When you join multiple tables in SQL the column names may collide and the usual way how to make them not to collide is to separately list returned columns whose names would be overlapping in multiple tables. Knex doesn't have any information for example how it could automatically prefix column names with table name. You might want to use `objection.js` or some other higher level library to be able to for example fetch relations as nested objects.

Comment: I've managed to get this working by replacing the first line of your code with `const query = knex(PageModel.tableName).select(\`${PageModel.tableName}.*\`);`, so if you just edit it, I will accept this answer as the correct one. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmmm... maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question, now that I think about it, but I only wanted the `page` table. The joins were necessary because of the filtering.

Comment: @Jakov Adding that `.select('MainTable.*')` is good solution in that case 

Answer (score -2):

The problem is **where after** `from(PageModel.tableName)`.
You are building something like:

```
select x from foo where foo.z join bar.y
```

To build a query join the right way:

```
select * from users join account where (users.account=account.id)
```

With Knwex is

```
knex('users').join('account').where((builder) => builder.where('user.account','account.id'))
```

You can test your query here http://michaelavila.com/knex-querylab/

Check it out [http://knexjs.org/#Builder-where](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-innerJoin) and http://knexjs.org/#Builder-innerJoin

Comment: Sorry for having to down vote. Joins and actually not built like that (at least with knex) and you are passing `account.id` as a string value literal not as column reference.